# Select radio button functions on html table row

Tags: javascript, html

I write the below code to get the radio button value to disable the table row. But getElementById/ getElementByName is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value ="1" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio"  name="r1" value="2" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
//alert("Test");
  var x = document.getElementByName("r1").value;
  alert(x);
  if(x ==1 ){
  document.getElementByValue("2").disabled = true;
  } 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alert is also not popping up. Is anything wrong here? I want to use plain JavaScript and html here.

Comment: alert(x) itself is not working. It seems getElementByName is also not working.

Comment: it is getElementsByName https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: @CuongNguyen :- I used getElementsByName . But the x value is coming undefined. What would be the problem here.?

Comment: getElementsByName returns all the elements with that name in the form of array, since you have two, your array would be [ inputElement1, inputElement2], doesn't look like you are using the right function to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `querySelector`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("[name=r1]"))
console.log(document.querySelector('[value="2"]'))
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="1"></td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="2"></td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `checked` property to fetch the value and then apply logic accordingly.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('disabled'));
  let tr = e.parentElement.parentElement;
  if (e.checked)
    tr.classList.add('disabled');
  else
    tr.classList.remove('disabled');
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" onchange="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="2" onchange="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is not disabling the other row when I selected row.

Comment: so, when checkbox is selected, what needs to be disabled? its not clear from the OP

Answer (score 0):

My attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table name="myTable">
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="r1" value ="1" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio"  name="r1"  value="2" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x1 = document.getElementsByName('r1')[0].checked;
  var x2 = document.getElementsByName('r1')[1].checked;
  if(x1){
      document.getElementsByName('r1')[1].disabled = true;
      // element[1]->parent->parent
      // r1[value=2]->td->tr
      document.getElementsByName('r1')[1].parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome.. this code is working. But how to apply to disable color when row is disabled?

Comment: I wanted to disable a complete row, even if the row contains any checkbox also. How do I?

Comment: added code to change background color (it affect the table row)

Comment: see line `document.getElementsByName('r1')[1].parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';`

Comment: change `'blue'` to whatever color you want